esta bien que una clase conosca otra clase y sus hijos?
quiero modelar un formulario con campos dinamicos en java, tengo la clase Campo que contiene una descripcion(String), un tipo de campo(Enum) y un objeto que representa el contenido(Entrada).
la entrada es una clase abstracta que tiene como hijos los distintos tipos de entrada que puede tener, como si es texto(EntradaTexto) contiene un string, o un campo multiple(EntradaMultiple) tiene una lista de strings.
el tema es que al crear una instancia de campo, quiero pasar al constructor la descripcion y el tipo de campo, y que genere una instancia de entrada que sea la indicada por el enum. podria hacerlo facil con un switch, pero entonces el campo no solo deberia conocer a la clase entrada, sino que a todas sus subclases y me parece medio mal. alguien podria darme una idea de como evitarlo?

Lo que dices suena mucho a patrón Factory, donde tienes una clase encargada de generar otras que todas cumplen un mismo "contrato" (normalmente a través de la implementación de una interfaz concreta). Obviamente la factoría sabe cómo inicializar todas las posibles clases, no es nada "malo". De hecho, lo bueno que tiene es que centralizas la inicialización de cada una de estas posibles clases en un mismo sitio en vez de tener la lógica toda por ahí "separada". Sin un ejemplo claro es difícil saber cual sería la mejor manera, y aún así... la pregunta está completamente basada en opiniones +


y las preguntas basadas en opiniones no son correctas en SO. Por qué está basada en opiniones? Porque en programación es muy raro que exista una única manera de hacer las cosas, y lo que para uno puede ser la manera más "correcta" para otro puede no serlo.

